# Pegar valores do select multiple

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou tentando passar os valores de um select multiple pro PHP. Já pesquisei exemplos na internet (inclusive meu código está igual aos exemplos que vi), mas o comando "echo" não me mostra nada. Podem me ajudar ? Obrigada.

```
$funcao = $_POST['funcao'];
$frutas = $_POST['frutas'];

if($funcao == 'copiar') {
    foreach ($frutas as &$item) {
        echo "Frutas escolhidas: ".$item."<br>";
    }
    exit;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="frmfrutas" action="rascunho.php" id="frmfrutas">
 <input type="hidden" name="funcao" id="funcao" value=""/>
 <select class="slMultiple" multiple="multiple" name="frutas[]" id="frutas" size="10">
   <option value="1">Maçã</option>
   <option value="2">Banana</option>
   <option value="3">Limão</option>
   <option value="4">Morango</option>
   <option value="5">Uva</option>
   <option value="6">Amora</option>
 </select>
 <input type="button" value="SELECIONAR" class="btn btn-primary" id='btSelecionar' name='btSelecionar'/>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btSelecionar', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#funcao").val("copiar");
  var self = $(this);
  $.ajax({
   url: "/rascunho.php",
   type: "POST",
   timeout:default_timeout,
   data: $("#frmfrutas").serialize(),
   beforeSend: function(){
    self.attr('disabled', 'true');
   },
   success: function() {
    
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
    console.log(textStatus, jqXHR);
   },
   complete: function(){
    self.removeAttr('disabled');
   }
  });
 });
```

Comment: Fiz um teste com seu código e ele funcionou pra mim.
você tem que fazer a chamada por ajax?
Talvez seu problema seja em outro ponto.

Comment: Sério ? =( Na minha tela não aparece a listagem... Pelo console consigo ver as frutas selecionadas mas na tela não aparece ;/

Comment: Acho que nesse caso você tem que usar o `serializeArray` ao invés de `serialize` no data do ajax. Da um `print_r($_POST)` no PHP pra ver o que tá vindo.;;

Comment: Exatamente leticia.
Pelo código que você postou ele funciona exatamente para o que foi proposto, os dados são passados por ajax e o "echo" mostra no console o que foi impresso.
Se vc quiser atualizar alguma outra parte com o retorno do ajax, você tem que ajustar o "success" da sua chamada ajax. [Imagem](https://image.ibb.co/ng1Td5/Captura_de_tela_de_2017_05_11_14_58_23.png).

Comment: Obrigada a todos pela ajuda. Eu removi o `serialize()` e passei os parâmetros um a um. Deu certo ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1 - HTML** - Fiz uma mudança nos inputs:

```
<form method="post" name="frmfrutas" action="rascunho.php" id="frmfrutas">
<input type="hidden" name="funcao" id="funcao" value=""/>
<select class="slMultiple" multiple="multiple" name="frutas[]" id="frutas" size="10">
        <option>Maçã</option>
        <option>Banana</option>
        <option>Limão</option>
        <option>Morango</option>
        <option>Uva</option>
        <option>Amora</option>      

</select>
<button value="SELECIONAR" class="btn btn-primary" id='btSelecionar' name='btSelecionar'/>SELECIONAR</button>

</form>
```

**2 - Script**

```
$(document).on('click', '#btSelecionar', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#funcao").val("copiar");
    var self = $(this);
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
        url: "rascunho.php",
        type: "POST",
        timeout:default_timeout,
        data: $( "form" ).serialize();,
        beforeSend: function(){
            self.attr('disabled', 'true');
        },
        success: function() {

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            console.log(textStatus, jqXHR);
        },
        complete: function(){
            self.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

**3 -  rascunho.php, testei com os 3 códigos.**

```
  if (isset($_POST["funcao"])) {
    $optionArray = $_POST["frutas"];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($optionArray); $i++) {
        echo $optionArray[$i]."<br>";
    }
  }
```

**ou**

```
 if(!empty($_POST["frutas"]) and is_array($_POST["frutas"])) {
     $result = implode(' <br> ',$_POST["frutas"]);
     echo $result;
 }
```

**Ou**

```
foreach ($_REQUEST['frutas'] as $selectedOption){
     echo $selectedOption."<br>";
 }
```

Comment: Deu certo o modelo 2 aqui pra mim... Eu só substitui o `<br>` por vírgula e usei o `$result` na minha query. Obrigada !